# Printer output from java applet is no longer in vector format?

Tags: java, applet

I have an online sheet music generator that for draws sheet music graphics to an area about 600pixels square. This looks OK on the screen but if printed each note would look blocky. 
I always used to be able to print this applet in Internet explorer and get a full vector output of the sheet music so the notes were perfectly rounded, even though they are only a dozen pixels in radius.

Sometime over the summer there must have been an update to java, or (internet explorer?) so my printouts now look horribly blocky. Can anyone think of a reason for this?

I have two versions of my applet, one is double buffered for animation purposes,(which would obviously produce a rasterised image unsuitable for printing) the other draws straight to the screen which is the one which I have been using for printing and has worked fine up until now!
Any help would be much appreciated as I use this program professionally and I have to print several thousand pages from it next week!

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone think of a reason for this?

The obvious answer to that might be 'a change to Java', which can be tested by disabling the later Java version in the [Java Control Panel](http://pscode.org/player.jnlp) (1), and using the earlier version only.

(1) Java Control Panel

1. (Close the Java Cache Viewer.)
2. Navigate to the Java tab of the JCP.
3. Select the View button
4. In the Java Runtime Environment Settings dialog, check the earlier versions, uncheck the later ones.

#### Java Runtime Environment Settings dialog

[image: Java Runtime Environment Settings dialog]

#### If that works

Use the earlier version for the 'several thousand pages'.

Comment: Ok, been busy the past week but finally got round to this. Thanks for the answer Andrew. It seemed like such an obvious solution that I was sure it would work! However apart from showing a dialogue whenever the applet loads saying "The required version of java 1.6.0_20 is not the latest" etc etc there is no difference in print output. My brother's laptop is running the same version of java 1.6.0_20 and it prints vector format (Print preview in IE is in vector format also) Could this be a problem with display drivers?

Comment: *"showing a dialogue"* There are choices in the dialog.  What is it that you click? If the problem is IE, it might be necessary to a) use another browser or b) launch the applet using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  And before I forget, what version JRE does the Java Console report is running?

Comment: The dialogue says "The required version of java 1.6.0_20 is not the latest and may not contain the latest security updates:The application requires an earlier version of Java, do you wish to continue?" The buttons are "Run" and "Cancel" I have never been able to print java applets from Mozilla or Chrome. By Java console do you mean the runtime settings panel you have above? I have 1.6.0_20 selected and the others disabled. I'll try the webstart method and get back to you. The problem is I need to be able to set print mode to portrait and scale the graphics to fill the page.

Comment: <head-desk/>  I mean, **Do you click run or cancel?** (Sheesh)  *"By Java console do you mean the runtime settings panel you have above?"* No, I mean the Java Console (just like I said).  There is an Advanced tab of the JCP that allows us to configure whether the Java Console automatically opens on launching an applet or JWS app.  Set it to open automatically, and look in it for the JRE version and any suspicious output.

Comment: Sorry, I'd forgotten about the console, so long since I programmed this thing. When I click "Run" on the aforementioned dialog the console says: "Using JRE version 1.6.0_20-b02 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM" followed by "Detected from bootclasspath: C:\\PROGRA~1\\Java\\jre7\\lib\\deploy.jar"   If I click "Cancel" then I get an empty box instead of the applet saying "error, click here for details" . If I click it then Java crashes and takes IE with it.

Comment: On point of note, checking the console output on my brother's computer; there is no reference to "Detected from bootclasspath: C:\\PROGRA~1\\Java\\jre7\\lib\\deploy.jar" Also the control panel icon for Java on my brother's computer says "Java(32-bit)" whereas mine just says "Java". Both computers are running identical OS, Windows 7 Ultimate, 64 bit

Comment: *""Detected from bootclasspath: .."*  You can ignore that message.  The important part is the earlier bit.  That message is a side-effect of using an earlier JRE.